# $P(E|H)$ in a coin-flip problem

Tags: probability

I am looking for a simple verification of my thinking:

For the question, "what is the probability of observing a total of $k$ heads when flipping $n$ coins, if one **particular** of the $n$ coins is known to be heads?" my answer is the probability of observing $k-1$ using $n-1$ coins.

and

For the question, "what is the probability of observing a total of $k$ heads when flipping $n$ coins, if one **particular** of the $n$ coins is known to be tails?" my answer is the probability of observing $k$ using $n - 1$ coins.

Is my logic correct?

**Note:** I suppose another way to think of "particular" is to think of a marked coin among the $n$ and considering that this coin is known to be heads (or tail).

Comment: Well, let's try $k=1,n=2$.  For the first:  knowing that one coin is $H$ means we are in one of $HH,TH,HT$ with equal probability.  Thus the probability of seeing a total of one $H$ is $\frac 23$ which is not what your conjecture gives.

Comment: You just made me realize my description of the problem is wrong. I didn't realize that writing "one of the coins" as opposed to "one particular coin" matters. Please see my edit.

Comment: Yes, that makes a big difference.  If you say "the first coin is $H$" then your expression is correct.

Comment: Just to be clear, you believe my stated logic is correct if I consider "the first coin" in the sequence (or, I suppose, any particular or marked coin)?

Comment: Yes.  Your reasoning is correct if we specify a single coin.

Answer (score 1):

I will use 1, 0 instead of H (head) and T (tails) below, i feel it is simpler to type. Let us consider the particular case of $n=3$ coins, and we let $k$ be one of $0,1,2,3$.

(1) The conditional probability w.r.t. the fact that there is at least one H (1).

All possibilities, the "big probability space" for modeling the problem is $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{\times3}$, the cartesian product of three copies of the space modeling one coin flip. It has $2^3=8$ elements. Now the "restricted space" is the subspace $\Omega'=\Omega-\{000\}$. (I will write please the elements as words instead of tuples, so $000$ is short for $(0,0,0)$.) Then $k$ heads occur respectively
$$
\binom 30\ ,\ 
\binom 31\ ,\ 
\binom 32\ ,\ 
\binom 33
$$
many times
in $\Omega$, thus with probability $\binom 3k/2^3$ in $\Omega$. In the "restricted space", we count one less element for the first case, thus respectively for $k=0,1,2,3$
$$
\binom 30-1\ ,\ 
\binom 31\ ,\ 
\binom 32\ ,\ 
\binom 33
$$
many times, and the probability is obtained by dividing with $|\Omega'|=|\Omega-1|=2^3-1$.
So the conditional probability asked for is $0$ for $k=0$, and $\binom 3k/(2^3-1)$.

Try to count considering explicitly the elements of the space $\Omega$:

```
000   - not in Omega'
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

For a general $n$ we have for $k=0$ the conditional probability $0$, else, for $k>0$ the corresponding $\binom nk/(2^n-1)$.

(2) The conditional probability w.r.t. the fact that there is at least one T (0).

Same argument. Answer:

For a general $n$ we have for $k=n$ the conditional probability $0$, else, for $k<n$ the corresponding $\binom nk/(2^n-1)$.

Comment: I am sorry to have made you venture this answer when my question was imprecise.